Find a name and list data in another column excel
I have a list of data that the first column has many same names, and second column contains number. i wanna list the numbers of specific name. How can I make that?
I tried UNIQUE formula to list the numbers but i don't know how can i list a specific name

FILTER function will does it.

You can use the FILTER function instead of UNIQUE.
If your excel has the below data,



Name
Number




Alice
10


Bob
15


Alice
20


Charlie
30


Bob
25



=FILTER(B2:B6, A2:A6="Alice")
which gives,



Result




10


20




If you need to have filter in place, use the Filter command from "Editing/Sort&Filter":


The best way was Filter formula because it is dynamic. Thanks for you answer bro
